# Search component not displaying on app component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get a search bar to display on my main app in React. To do this I have created a new component called searchBox to be used later and therefore I can't just directly app the input to my App.js file.

My code for my App.JS file looks like :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CardList from './CardList';
import searchBox from './searchBox';
import { robots } from './robots';


const App = () => {
return (
    <div>
        <h1> Contacts </h1>
        <searchBox />
        <CardList robots={robots} />
    </div>  
)
}

export default App;
```

My searchbox.js file looks like :

```
import React from 'react';

const searchBox = () => {
return(
    <input type='search' placeholder='search contacts' />
);
}

export default searchBox;
```

The header is displaying but the searchbox is not. I have the file save in the src folder as searchBox so I don't think the issue is to do with saving the file in the wrong location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User defined components must be capitalized.

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Answer (score 2):

Can you capitalize S in your searchBox? React expects component names to start with capital letter.